# How to pass datepicker change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm checking a date entered with a datepicker control in jquery from an Html.TextBoxFor helper:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.mydate, new { @class = "datepicker", maxlength = 10, @onBlur = "chkDate"})%>
```

The datepicker mask for the textbox appears to be MM/DD/YYYY . So, my script checks for an underscore and displays an error.  This works if the user igonores the datepicker and tries to enter a date freehand but not if the datepicker is used.  When a date is chosen, the value passed to my script is still underscores and no value.  Here's my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("blur", "input[name=mydate]",
    function chkDate() {


        var len = $("input[name=mydate]").val().length;
        var date = $("input[name=mydate]").val();

        var month = date.slice(0, 2);
        var day = date.slice(3, 5);
        var year = date.slice(6, 10);
        alert("chkBirthday " + month);

        if (month == '__') {
            document.getElementById("MainContent_ErrorMessage").visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("MainContent_ErrorMessage").innerHTML = 'No date has been entered.  Please enter a date';
        }

    });
```

There's an event onChange associated with datepicker.  Is this what I should be using?  If so, how do I specify that in my helper and what script changes do I need to make?

Comment: What "datepicker" are you using? jQuery UI? If so, where is it initialized?

Comment: A fairly nasty (but very effective) alternative solution could be to make the input read-only, forcing the user to use the datepicker.

Comment: Yes, it's ui-datepicker in jQuery UI.  Forcing users to use this is a nice thought but not practical! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name=mydate]",function (){
     var len = $(this).val().length;
     var date = $(this).val();

     var month = date.slice(0, 2);
     var day = date.slice(3, 5);
     var year = date.slice(6, 10);
     alert("chkBirthday " + month);

     if (month == '__') {
         document.getElementById("MainContent_ErrorMessage").visibility = 'visible';
         document.getElementById("MainContent_ErrorMessage").innerHTML = 'No date has been entered.  Please enter a date';
     }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the popular JQuery UI's Datepicker, weirdly enough they are not entitled events but callbacks that can handle this event. See [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) or onClose.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JQuery UI's datepicker.  I just added a little test:  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                onSelect: function () {
                    alert("chk " + $("input[name=date]").val()); 
                }  I'm using Chrome which doesn't display my alert.
            });